# numFailedIdleTestsDefaultUser (db connections silently failed during idle time)

Tags: hibernate, c3p0, jboss6.x, hornetq, jboss-mdb

I just configured my c3p0 pool properties but after some time i can see ( from monitoring tool ) the field "**numFailedIdleTestsDefaultUser**" is increasing. Do we need to worry about this ??. IF yes how to resolve this.

Regareds
Veera

Answer (score 0):

On its own, this isn't anything you need to worry about, at all. On the contrary, it's normal and expected, as long as new failures are infrequent.

Lots of things can cause idle Connections to eventually fail in a long-lived application. Most commonly, Connections will simply time-out. You can probably adjust this in database settings, but you don't have to, it isn't a problem. If you've configured good Connection testing, broken Connections will be noticed and purged from the pool and replaced without issue. Other things that can cause idle Connections to fail tests are network or DB outages and stuff happening. As long as new failures are occasional, there's really nothing to be concerned about.

Comment: Thanks steve for you confirmation.